# Ge 10$ option expired june21

Tags: investing

What happened to my ge option June 21 $10 I had sold 20 of them and when they expired I was charged an additional $802

Comment: Please elaborate more. Is the option automatically executed (required opt-out) as stated in the contract?

Comment: Hi Dave, welcome to the stack. Unfortunately we will need to know a lot more about the contract terms of the options, particularly the auto-execution statement as mentioned below. This is a great question but could just do with a little more information so don't let the downvotes get you down!

Comment: Dave - the question is on track to be closed as unclear. If you return and edit to clarify, it would likely be reopened. I hope to see you do that.

Answer (score 1):

You provided insufficient information.  Were you long or short the stock as well?  Was this a put or a call?  Indicating the commission charged would also be helpful.

GE closed at $10.48 on Friday.  If this was a $10 put, it expired worthless.  If it was a standard $10 call, it expired in-the-money and would have been auto-exercised by the Option Clearing Corp.  That would result in the  sale of the stock.  Since $802 was a debit, this can't be the case since you would have received a credit for the sale of 2,000 shares of stock.  Something else is going on here.

My guess is that you may have been involved in adjusted GE option contracts.  4 months ago, GE announced the  spin-off and subsequent merger of its transportation business with Wabtec (WAB). That resulted in an a non-standard contract requiring the delivery of  100 shares of GE and cash in lieu of approximately 0.005371 fractional  shares of WAB. The last of these expired 6/21.

It's hard enough for many people to understand standard options.  An adjusted option takes it to a new level.  If this  was the case then you can read about it by Googling:

> Option Adjustment General Electric OCC

Sorry, but I can't provide the link because I am registered with the OCC and the web address contains my real name.

If you were not involved with adjusted options then I have no clue what could have happened here.

Comment: He said "an additional 802" - maybe he sold a naked call, and he then saw that premium + 802 get debited. The 2 number can add up to the right range. The buyer could have exercised anything from $10.45 - $10.71 on Friday.

Comment: I don't follow.  When American options are exercised (which GE is), the underlying is involved in settlement. With a standard GE option, selling a naked call  results in the sale of 100 shares at the strike which in this case was $10 and a debit of $1,000 and a commission fee if he pays for asssignment and exercise.  It would make no difference whatsover what GE's price was when the call was exercised.  My guess is that the $802 is due to the attached cash requirement for the adjusted contract, or approx $40 per contract. Stopping here since all of this is speculation. Need details from OP.

Comment: Let's see if OP returns. I was just suggesting that the broker immediately bought the stock instead of leaving OP short. In which case, the numbers work. OP account is 'unregistered' making his return 'unlikely'.